# Win 7 accessing large files uses 100% RAM

Tags: windows, memory

Running Win 7 64-bit SP1 with 8 GB RAM. I first noticed this problem when using the GUI to copy some large (5+ GB) files from one disk to another. What happens is the physical memory in use rises quite quickly to 100% and the system comes to a crawl. If I just start to access the file in a media player (it is a movie) the memory usage climbs up slowly but eventually reaches 100%.

When copying the same files via XCOPY I do not have this problem.

Using RAMMAP I see most of the memory usage is under "Mapped File" and is allocated under the "Active" column. If I select "Empty System Working Set" the RAM usage drops back down but then starts to climb back up.

Any ideas on what I can check/test to eliminate this issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you use xcopy, the system doesn't slow down?

Answer (score 0):

You have to request an updated version of the **[Microsoft Windows Dynamic Cache Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/microsoft-windows-dynamic-cache-service)** that runs on Win7/Server 2008 R2 from the Microsoft support to limit the file cache and prevent it from "eating" all your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update your "Microsoft Windows Dynamic Cache" Service as proposed by @magicandre1981 then you could always use the the Sysinternals tool [Cacheset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897561) to try out individual settings. Be aware that this can have adverse side-effects on your system.